# Android: How to fix delay in progress bar showing up when saving image

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a button which when clicked saves a bitmap to directory and then passes the file path of the saved image to another activity. However, there is a delay usually of about 2 seconds (especially if the bitmap size is large) before the next activity starts. So to let user know that bitmap is being saved during that 2 second waiting time, I added a progress bar which becomes visible when button is clicked. However, the issue I am encountering is that the progress bar does not show up immediately on click of button, instead it shows up just a few milliseconds before next activity starts. How do I make progress bar show up immediately on click of button?

Below is a snippet of code relating to the issue:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show progress bar

                if (progBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) { // if progress bar is visible


                    Bitmap cropped_image_bitmap = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(); // uses android-image-cropper library

                    // Save bitmap to directory by calling SaveImage() located in SaveToDirectory.java class
                    //SaveImage() method returns the filepath of image being saved
                    String saved_img_filepath = SaveToDirectory.SaveImage(getApplicationContext(), cropped_image_bitmap);

                    if (saved_img_filepath != null) {
                        //finish(); // ready to end current activity

                        //following are the steps to pass values from current activity to another activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImgpostActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("IMAGE_URI", saved_img_filepath);

                        //start next activity
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: will you please show your xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

is surely running on UI Thread,

I guess that

> Bitmap cropped_image_bitmap = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(); //
>   uses android-image-cropper library

is run on UI Thread too,

What happened is when you force progress bar view to show, it takes some time when ui redraw phase will coming up, before that happened, you already call another command like getCroppedImage which consumed all UI Thread progress, that why you faced the result like screen freezing

IMO, if my guessing is right, the solution is to move 'getCroppedImage()' to secondary or anonymous thread (AsnycTask) like..

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Bitmap cropped_image_bitmap = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(); // uses android-image-cropper library
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where exactly should this code be placed? Inside onCreate? Inside onClick?

Comment: Thanks. I did some modification to your code and created a separate class for the AsyncTask and and called the class from within onClick and it worked.

Comment: also, better to keep asynctask as class variable instead of anonymous like I did, to prevent memory leak